# Apache redirect doesn't work on one specific subdomain

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, redirect, apache2

I found a few similar questions, but nothing that quite seemed to describe my situation, so apologies in advance if this is a duplicate.

I am running apache2 on an AWS instance of Ubuntu 16.04, and one specific subdomain is not redirecting properly.

If I type "rebecca.example.com" into my browser, I only get the default Ubuntu "Apache works" page. If I type "intranet.example.com" into my browser, however, it redirects to https://rebecca.example.com as I would expect. I considered that perhaps this could be due to ServerName vs ServerAlias, but I tried switching them and restarting apache, and found that the rebecca subdomain still would not redirect. Additionally, this only started about a week ago, and is only affecting this one deployment (other deployments on the same server both within the same conf file and in others are unaffected.) As far as I can, there has not been any change to DNS. `apachectl configtest` returns 'Syntax OK.'

Bellow is a sample of my conf file (I hid the IP/paths, but this is otherwise an accurate representation)

```
<Directory "/var/www/github.com/org/repo">
    Require all denied
    Require ip 127.0.0.1
    Require ip XX.XXX.XXX.XXX/XX
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName intranet.example.com

    Redirect permanent / https://rebecca.example.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName intranet.example.com

    SetEnv API_CREDENTIALS /path/to/credentials/api.json
    SetEnv JWT_SECRET superSECRET

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/github.com/org/repo/html"

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/certificate.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/key.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "/path/to/chain.ca-bundle"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName rebecca.example.com

    Redirect permanent / https://rebecca.example.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName rebecca.example.com

    SetEnv API_CREDENTIALS /path/to/credentials/api.json
    SetEnv JWT_SECRET superSECRET
</VirtualHost>

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/github.com/org/repo/html"

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/certificate.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/key.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "/path/to/chain.ca-bundle"
</VirtualHost>
```

In short, my question is why might this occur on only one subdomain, and what could I do to troubleshoot/fix it?

Answer (score 0):

That's an odd one. Things to try:

- Check that rebecca.example.com resolves to the same address as intranet.example.com.
- Give rebecca.example.com its own VirtualHost, to isolate any problems from intranet.example.com.
- Use [mod_info](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_info.html) to check that the config is what you expect.
- Turn up `LogLevel` and check the logs for more information.

Then reload the configuration, clear your browser cache (browsers cache redirects) and try again.

Comment: Thank you, although no luck so far.  
Chrome extension that displays the IP of the site I'm on shows the same for both, and both gave the same info on an `nslookup`  
I gave rebecca it's own VirtualHost (updated the example to reflect this) however, after a configtest (Syntax OK) and a graceful restart, same result. (I kept intranet pointing to the same `https://rebecca..`)  
LogLevel was already set to debug, so I tried it on trace8 and trace5, however, I was still unable to figure anything out from the logs.  
I haven't gotten `mod_info` working yet, will post back if I do